# Views 3: Getting related content from node ref field

Tags: views, nodes

Okay, i have the following node types:

Band
Story

Every story content **links to a band** via the node reference module for Drupal 7, now i'd like to pull related story content thats linked to the band when i **view the current node** that links to band X.

To give you an beter example:

When the story, "helloween reveals new album" links to helloween, i'd like to display all the related story's about helloween in that view...

Comment: Hi, do you use Panels ?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not quite clear whether you want to show band information when viewing a band-story node or to show band stories when viewing a band node. I'm assuming it's the second one.

1. Create a View with "Content" under "Show", and choose "Band Story" as the node type.
   [image]
2. Clear the check box to create a page or make a block if you want. That's up to you:
3. Save and continue to Views UI.
4. In the Views UI, make sure you have 2 filters added - Node is published, and the node's type is Band Story.
5. Default sort criteria would be "Newest first". Change it if you want.
6. Add a new contextual filter.
7. In the add contextual filter, choose the field that **refers to Band node**. This field should be **in the Band Story node type**.
8. Add the argument. You will get the argument's settings page.
9. Under "When the filter value is NOT available", choose "Provide default value". Under "Type" select list, choose "Content ID from URL". 
   [image]
10. You can optionally add a validation criteria if you allow the node reference field to refer other node types than "band" as follows.

[image]
11.  That's it! Save the View and put the block (you have to give a name to it) in the sidebar (or anywhere else). it will inherit the current node's ID and will show Band Story nodes that have this node ID in its node reference field.

Answer (score 0):

### **If you use Panels**

Simply don't use **nid** as contextual filter, but your **entity reference field** and send that field's value of your story node to the view. Don't use any relationship.

---

### **If you don't use Panels**

I expect the only thing you can send to your view is the story's nid.

Then the only way I see (I hope people can provide you with a simpler one) is with a **[PhP filter](http://drupal.org/project/views_php)** :

1. Contextual filter : **nid**, **exclude** (I guess you want all the *other* stories about your band)
2. Relationship : **your reference field**, **require this relationship**
3. Field : **Content title**, without relationship
4. Field : **nid**, **with relationship, and exclude it from display**
5. Filter criteria : **PhP** with the following code :

// In "**setup code**" we will set into $static the nid referenced by the story with the 'field_reference' field

```
$node = node_load($view->args[0]);
$static = $node->'node_field_data_yourreferencefield'['und'][0]['target_id'];
```

// In "**filter code**", we will exclude the rows where field value is different from $static

```
if ($data->'yourreferencefield' == $static) {return FALSE;} else {return TRUE;}
```

If you don't know the names to use for your fields, don't hesitate to dpm($data) and / or dpm($view->args[0]) in your php filter.

Comment: The view will be embed into the node it self via a custom template file, like this: 
<?php print views_embed_view('related_content');?>

Further more, to awnser #1's question: When viewing a story about a certain band, in this case 'helloween' i'd like to show the related 'helloween' story's nodes in content type 'story' with this view.. hoping its a bit more clear now.

Comment: Then you can priorly do a node_load and get the value of your reference field, and send it as an arg : <?php print views_embed_view('related_content', 'yourdisplay', $red_nid);?> and use the entity ref field as a contextual filter of the view, simply as that.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but i don't realy have any knowlegde from php except some very basic things, like printing stuff and so on.... Can you give me an example piece of code? :)